# C# WPF: Hyperlink без NavigateUri

Tags: c#, wpf

Такая проблема: хочу сделать гиперссылку, которая не будет открывать страницу в интернете, а просто запустит метод. Как Button запускает метод из свойства Click, так и я хочу чтобы Hyperlink запускала метод, описанный в свойстве RequestNavigate без открытия веб-страницы из NavigateUri.

Если без свойства NavigateUri не обойтись, то что туда можно написать, чтобы ничего не происходило?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно  `NavigateUri`  вообще указывать, самый простой способ просто завернуть `Hyperlink` в `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock>                                
   <Hyperlink Command="{Binding SomeCommand, ElementName=window}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">Link
   </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Вообще же, способов очень много, можете выбрать свой любимый [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122334/how-do-i-make-a-wpf-button-look-like-a-link)

Например, сделать кнопку и стилем заставить выглядеть ее как ссылку.